# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar error con phpmyadmin "Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine."?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hace poco que instalé Xampp en Ubuntu 14.04, phpmyadmin inicia bien sólo que cuando intento acceder a una base de datos me muestra el siguiente error:

```
#1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine
```

Intenté hacer unos cambios en el archivo config.ini.php dentro de la carpeta phpmyadmin pero aun no logro resolverlo.

Comment: Cierra la sesión en Phpmyadmin y vuelve a loguearte. Me sucede cuando tengo varias instancias de phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2):

Todas las tablas de phpMyAdmin están definidas en el archivo **create_tables.sql** del paquete sql por lo que puedes hacer un **import** de ese archivo,ó simplemente **crear** la tabla pma__tracking de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__tracking` (
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `schema_snapshot` text NOT NULL,
  `schema_sql` text,
  `data_sql` longtext,
  `tracking` set('UPDATE','REPLACE','INSERT','DELETE','TRUNCATE','CREATE DATABASE','ALTER DATABASE','DROP DATABASE','CREATE TABLE','ALTER TABLE','RENAME TABLE','DROP TABLE','CREATE INDEX','DROP INDEX','CREATE VIEW','ALTER VIEW','DROP VIEW') default NULL,
  `tracking_active` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`db_name`,`table_name`,`version`)
)
  COMMENT='Database changes tracking for phpMyAdmin'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Fuente : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055394/1146-table-phpmyadmin-pma-tracking-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 2):

Yo presente el mismo problema lo que hice fue actualizar el phpmyadmin a su versión actual 4.5.2, lo descargue de su página oficial https://www.phpmyadmin.net/ 
Y luego lo que hice fue eliminar la carpeta del phpmyadmin que ya tenía, realice una copia de esta misma por si algo llegase a quedar mal y luego copie la que descargue y me fui a la copia que tenía copie el archivo config a la nueva que descargue, reinicie el navegador y listo asunto arreglado